# In Kafka, Is it possible to have replication for selective partitions from one topic?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, bigdata, hadoop2

As I understand that we can have replication at topic level where all partitions of a Topic will be replicated across cluster. But can we control replication of only selective  partitions from a topic?

Answer (score 0):

No. From the [doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#replication)

> Kafka replicates the log for each topic's partitions across a
>   configurable number of servers (you can set this replication factor on
>   a topic-by-topic basis).

If you think about the design of Kafka, what are Topics and Partitions, it makes sense:

- Topics are streams or category of messages, so it's a way to organise your messages based on their type and content
- partitions are basically a concept to handle smoothly distribution. They are based on a Key, but the original idea is to split your messages evenly on all partitions of one Topic. It's not really designed to organise messages for business use, but for architectural constraint.